# iOS UI automation testing

Tags: java, ios, xcode, automated-tests, appium

I'm a beginner in mobile iOS testing and I'm trying to write some tests, for example:

**Click "Install" on intallation popup** --> **Check if app is installed on the device**

But I can't find any tools that make possible to execute such test. So far I've been using Appium, but it requires app or bundleId to run tests. Is there any way to automate popups/browsing the device?

Comment: are you looking to test downloading the app from the appstore? no tools wouldn't let you do that. This is also not something you should test. When testing you should only test what you own, and you don't own the app download. If the test failed because it couldn't be downloaded, how would you fix the problem? you couldn't because it would be up to apple to fix

Comment: No, I'm installing app via MDM software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with popups as simple IOS elements.
Or you can force appium to auto enable (or disable) any popup by adding appropriate capability `(“autoAcceptAlerts”,true);`

Comment: Sure, but Appium also requires app or bundleId, is it possible to avoid it?

Comment: no, you cant. you can run some dummy app and then open another one, but you have to run some particular application